Replacing a part of a SQL text string via an Update statment
Im trying to update a set of strings I have with duplicate values but I only want to update the "second" set of duplicate values and not the first. This value stored in a string field in a SQL Server Database. Here are the strings in question:
Standard Activity Note |   Type of Recovery: Final |   Date of Member Settlement: 12/20/2023 |   TPL: 10/06/2023 |   UM:  |   UIM: 12/20/2023 |   n/a |   Total amount of member settlement: $30,755.00 |   TPL: $22,275.00 |   UM:  |   UIM: $8,500.00 |   n/a | 

Standard Activity Note |   Type of Recovery: Final |   Date of Member Settlement: 9/13/2023 |   TPL: 09/13/2023 |   UM:  |   UIM:  |   n/a |   Total amount of member settlement: $50,000.00 |   TPL: $50,000.00 |   UM:  |   UIM:  |   n/a | 

Standard Activity Note |   Type of Recovery: Final |   Date of Member Settlement: 10/9/2023 |   TPL: 10/09/2023 |   UM:  |   UIM:  |   n/a |   Total amount of member settlement: $7,500.00 |   TPL: $7,500.00 |   UM:  |   UIM:  |   n/a |   

I am trying to update ONLY the part of the text where it says TPL: and UM: to TPL Amount: and UM Amount:. Problem is that it exists twice in the string so if I run an update to replace substring of TPL: it'll update both.
Any ideas on how to update the second instance of the TPL and UM string? The string has at least pipes in it so that may help. Additionally I need the update to be more dynamic as I have about 200 rows that need to be updated and cant just update one line at a time.
UPDATE dbo.xxx
SET Value = REPLACE(Value, 'TPL:', 'TPL Amount:')
WHERE text_description like '%tpl:%'

UPDATE dbo.xxx
SET Value = REPLACE(Value, 'UM:', 'UM Amount:')
WHERE text_description like '%UM:%'

I believe above will work but it will update both values if they exist I only want it to update the second iteration of the text in the string.

search for the first occurrence of each value to be replaced.  create two variables one with the LEFT left portion up to that value one with the right after it.  use the replace function on the right portion and then concatenate both values back together.  This assumes it will never have UM: or TLP: more than twice.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Seems like the real problem is your design. These clearly distinct values, so you should be storing them in separate columns, not one long string.in a single column. The fact you want to UPDATE only part of the value cements that this point.

Is the string to be replaced always 'TPL: $' or 'UM: |'? If so, use a longer pattern and replacement. Aside: You should use delimited patterns to avoid problems with future substrings, e.g. '%UM:%' will cheerfully match '| SUM: 99.44 |'. '%| UM:%' won't.

You can use CHARINDEX to find the first occurance of '|   UM:' . Then perform the replacements on the substring starting 7 chrs beyond that index.
UPDATE dbo.xxx
SET text_description = SUBSTRING(text_description, 1, CHARINDEX('|   UM:',text_description) + 7)  +
    REPLACE( 
            REPLACE(
                     SUBSTRING(text_description, CHARINDEX('|   UM:',text_description) +7, LEN(text_description)-CHARINDEX('|   UM:  |',text_description) +7), 
                     '|   UM:', 
                     '|   UM Amount:'),
             '|   TPL:', 
             '|   TPL Amount:'
          ) 
WHERE text_description like '%tpl:%'
      OR
      text_description like '%UM:%'

fiddle

You can try tokenization method via SQL Server's XML and XQuery.
Notable points:

First CROSS APPLY is tokenizing column value as XML.
Second CROSS APPLY is using XQuery FLWOR expression to traverse an
XML, find 2nd occurrence of "TPL:" and "UM:" strings via XPath predicate /root/r[...][2], and replace
then with desired values.
There is some additional string massaging, i.e. cast as xs:token?, etc. to handle spaces.

SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('Standard Activity Note |   Type of Recovery: Final |   Date of Member Settlement: 12/20/2023 |   TPL: 10/06/2023 |   UM:  |   UIM: 12/20/2023 |   n/a |   Total amount of member settlement: $30,755.00 |   TPL: $22,275.00 |   UM:  |   UIM: $8,500.00 |   n/a | '),
('Standard Activity Note |   Type of Recovery: Final |   Date of Member Settlement: 9/13/2023 |   TPL: 09/13/2023 |   UM:  |   UIM:  |   n/a |   Total amount of member settlement: $50,000.00 |   TPL: $50,000.00 |   UM:  |   UIM:  |   n/a | ');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '|';

UPDATE t
SET tokens = REPLACE(x.query('data(/r)').value('.', 'VARCHAR(1024)'),SPACE(4), ' |  ')
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(tokens,SPACE(2),SPACE(1)), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.query('
    let $tpl := /root/r[substring(text()[1] cast as xs:token?,1,4)="TPL:"][2]
    let $um := /root/r[substring(text()[1] cast as xs:token?,1,3)="UM:"][2]
    for $x in /root/r
    return if (($x)[1] is ($tpl)[1]) then <r>{concat("  TPL Amount:", substring($x/text()[1] cast as xs:token?, 5, 50))}</r>
        else if (($x)[1] is ($um)[1]) then <r>{concat("   UM Amount: ", substring($x/text()[1] cast as xs:token?, 4, 50))}</r>
        else $x
')) AS t2(x);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

